# Twig loop is not looping once but multiple times

Tags: php, symfony, for-loop, twig

Trying to loop through my query results and pass them into twig to print them, however it is printing them each at a time.   Is there a better way to loop through the results with twig?

I've tried different combinations of twig loops but it loops once and prints each results per `<li>` tag.

Here is my Twig code.

```
<ul>
    {% for status in status %}
            <li>{{ status }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

        {% for invoiceNumber in invoiceNumber %}
            <li>{{ invoiceNumber }}</li>
        {% endfor %}


        {% for createdAt in createdAt %}
            <li>{{ createdAt }}</li>
        {% endfor %}

        {% for amount in amount %}
            <li>{{ amount }}</li>
        {% endfor %}


        {% for sourceCode in sourceCode %}
            <li>{{ sourceCode }}</li>
        {% endfor %}

        {% for fundCode in fundCode %}
            <li>{{ fundCode }}</li>
        {% endfor %}


        {% for keyword in keyword %}
            <li>{{ keyword }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Here is what it prints

```
   <li>2
   <li>2
   <li>000035772641
   <li>000035772861
   <li>03/26/19
   <li>03/26/19
   <li>20
   <li>80
   <li>G19W2KACTB
   <li>K100
   <li>vvK100
```

What I would like for it to print is 
per `<ul>` tag

```
   <li>2
   <li>000035772641
   <li>03/26/19
   <li>20
   <li>G19W2KACTB
   <li>vvK100


   <li>2
   <li>000035772861
   <li>03/26/19
   <li>80
   <li>
   <li>K100
```

Id like to print each results withing 1 `<ul>` tag through a loop. Is anyone familiar with twig that might spot the problem and help me with a solution?

Comment: Paste you controller for showing what are you passing to the view.

Comment: @AythaNzt its a swiftmailer function that i am passing to the view.

Comment: @AythaNzt i have edit the original question and pasted the mailer function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show your full controller first.

Anyway, better and shorter way to loop over your query result is create something like this in Twig

```
    {% for result in results %}
        <ul>
            <li>{{ result.invoiceNumber }}</li>
            <li>{{ result.createdAt }}</li>
            <li>{{ result.amount }}</li>
            .......
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

Where result is single row in results array of fetched rows from DB

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to place all your values into an array inside your controller.

I don't know what your controller looks like, but you would need an array looking like this.

```html
  $results = array(
    array(
      'status' => "something",
      'invoiceNumber' => "123",
      'createdAt' => "2019-03-29",
     'amount' => 2.00,
     'sourceCode' => "<div>blah blah</div>",
     'fundCode' => "Something",
     'keyword' => "Something else"
    ),
    array(
      'status' => "something",
      'invoiceNumber' => "123",
      'createdAt' => "2019-03-29",
     'amount' => 2.00,
     'sourceCode' => "<div>blah blah</div>",
     'fundCode' => "Something",
     'keyword' => "Something else"
    )
    .....
  );
```

Essentially then you could loop your results like so:

```html
{% for result in results %}
  <ul>
     <li>{{ result.status }}</li>
     <li>{{ result.invoiceNumber }}</li>
     <li>{{ result.createdAt }}</li>
     <li>{{ result.amount }}</li>
     <li>{{ result.sourceCode }}</li>
     <li>{{ result.fundCode }}</li>
     <li>{{ result.keyword }}</li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

That should do the trick.